# Avoiding <fx:declarations> tags in mxml classes to boost performance?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5, mxml

According to "The bAS3 Class", all declarations in a mxml class that are within a `<fx:Declarations>` tag are in fact bindable. [[source]](http://www.brandondement.com/blog/category/actionscript/).

So now I'm wondering what that does to the application's performance. To boost maintainability in my code, I've made quite a lot declarations like that, but since I'm developing a mobile app, I'm after the maximum performance I can get.

Is it advisable to ditch the `<fx:Declarations>` stuff altogether in favor of performance? I know that binding is quite heavy in flex, which is why I avoided it wherever possible.

Comment: It's quite similar. Try adding `-keep-generated-actionscript` to your compiler settings to see the difference!

Comment: The act of Binding is generally a performance drag; making something Bindable is miniscule.  so, it depends how you're using the stuff you are declaring in the declarations.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt if declarations would hinder performance that much, unless the declarations are Factory objects that are used to create hundreds of components.  But it is correct that heavy databinding could eat into performance if the binding properties change a lot, so that would be the first thing to improve.  Remedy would include using    [Bindable("eventName")] instead of just    [Bindable], or ditch databinding, and use direct events.

Comment: I interpret the original question as saying he is just creating elements inside of an fx_Declarations and is not explicitly making things Bindable; but it is done behind the scenes by the Flex compiler.  The use of binding can be a performance drag.  Making something Bindable shouldn't.

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear. I don't need the binding, I solely use the declarations tags because it's a very convenient place to put stuff (such as Arrays with Views) as it can easily be altered even by non-programmers at the beginning of the MXML files without going through a lot of code. I guess a static AS class would to the same, without the unnecessary heavy binding though.